# Sound wont play correctly with Web Audio

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api, audiocontext

I am trying to play a wav file using AudioContext - it plays correctly when loaded with `<audio>` tag (as shown in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Persiancoffee/6v8dLt3f/7/)), but plays incorrectly when using AudioContext.

```
var startButton = document.getElementById('start-stream');
var wav = new wavefile.WaveFile();
startButton.onclick = function() {
  audioCtx = new AudioContext();
  wav.fromBase64(mydata);

  buffer = audioCtx.createBuffer(1, audioCtx.sampleRate * 3, audioCtx.sampleRate);

  // add audio data to buffer
  buffer.getChannelData(0).set(wav.getSamples());

  source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
  source.buffer = buffer;
  source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
  source.start();
};
```

Fiddle is here:  https://jsfiddle.net/Persiancoffee/6v8dLt3f/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `decodeAudioData()` function of the Web Audio API can decode WAV files which is why you don't need any external libraries for this use case. It will produce an `AudioBuffer` for you.

```
startButton.onclick = async function () {
    audioCtx = new AudioContext();

    const arrayBuffer = Uint8Array.from(
        atob(mydata),
        (character) => character.charCodeAt(0)
    ).buffer;

    buffer = await audioCtx.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer);
    
    source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = buffer;
    source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    source.start();
};
```

Here is a link to an updated version of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pzx0vg89/.